# How to aggregate returns in an excel UDF using the product formula

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I am trying to put the below formula into a UDF so that I can get a cumulative return when I aggregate monthly returns.

In excel the formula has to be recognized as an array so when I type it in I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the `{}` brackets around the formula.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I want to be able to just type in `returns_calc()` and select the range that would fit into the returns variable below.

```
{=(PRODUCT(1+returns/100)-1)*100}
```

Comment: `Range("A1").FormulaArray = "=(PRODUCT(1+returns/100)-1)*100"`

Comment: You can't use .FormulaArray inside a UDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `[ ]` notation in `Application.Evaluate` to calculate Array Formulas in VBA. Your above formula can be called in VBA **in just 1 line** as shown below

```
Sub Sample()
    MsgBox Application.Evaluate(["=(PRODUCT(1+returns/100)-1)*100"])
End Sub
```

Now modifying it to accept a range in a function, you may do this as well

```
Function returns_calc(rng As Range) As Variant
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Dim frmulaStr As String

    frmulaStr = "=(PRODUCT(1+(" & rng.Address & ")/100)-1)*100"
    returns_calc = Application.Evaluate([frmulaStr])

    Exit Function
Whoa:
    returns_calc = "Please check formula string" 'or simply returns_calc = ""
End Function
```

**EXAMPLE SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: @Siddarth, Note that - you don't need the [] - on my system you need to enter the UDF as an array formula using CSE - using an unqualified reference in Evaluate will always reference the active sheet - better to use a fully qualified range reference

Comment: Thank you so much that works great. Is there also a way I could use a shortcut for this like the autosum is alt + =?

Comment: @user1684273: I am sorry, I am not aware of a way where you can assign a shortcut to a UDF. You can do it for a normal procedure though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
Public Function Range_Product(theRange As Variant)
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim j As Long

    var = theRange.Value2
    Range_Product = 1#
    For j = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
        Range_Product = Range_Product * (1 + var(j, 1) / 100)
    Next j

    Range_Product = (Range_Product - 1) * 100
End Function
```